# In NodeJS selenium-webdriver, how do you get innerHTML of element

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I've gone through: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs and it doesn't have any information.  So, can someone help.

I have

```
var element = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.id("something"))
console.log('text='+element.getAttribute("inner‌​HTML"));
```

But doesn't work.  Most of the documentation appears to be for JAVA not nodeJS.  If you come across a .getText() function, I'm pretty sure that is JAVA. I actually just want the text part innerText, opposed to innerHTML.  But that might be asking too much.

Comment: I thought webdriver js was async? I'm surprised that element is not null when the console.log executes if it isn't in a callback.

Answer (score 13):

You can check innerHTML like this:

```
driver.executeScript(function() {
    return document.querySelector('#something').innerHTML;
  }).then(function(innerHTML) {
   //check content here 
  });
```

Comment: Never knew this was a thing! Awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Per the [webdriver.js](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#2011) docs:

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.myclass'));

myElement.getInnerHtml().then(function(html) {
    //do stuff with html here
});
```

Hope that helps! It's working for me using Node.js + Selenium / WebDriver, etc.